# How to get regex pattern for the string?

Tags: java, regex, java-11

There are lots of replacement which needs to be done in my string , so I am thinking if we can get the regex instead of replacing every word manually, Is there any way we can replace any word with "\?" to "? ", sample is shown below can someone help me with the regex pattern

```
    query = query.replaceAll("id\\?", "?");
    query = query.replaceAll("name\\?", "?");
    query = query.replaceAll("empid\\?", "?");
    query = query.replaceAll("value\\?", "?");
```

Comment: Try `query = query.replaceAll("((\w)+\\\?)+", "?");`. It will replace any word having `<any word>\?` with `?`

Comment: Invalid escape sequence (valid ones are  \b  \t  \n  \f  \r  \"  \'  \\ ) @KaustubhKhare

Comment: Make that (\\w).

Comment: doesnt work , ok thanku .. I will figure out something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
String query = "SELECT * FROM t WHERE id=id? AND name=name? AND empid=empid? AND value=value?";
query = query.replaceAll("\\w+\\?", "?");
System.out.println(query);
```

output:

```
SELECT * FROM t WHERE id=? AND name=? AND empid=? AND value=?
```

Comment: small and straight forward answer thanks @saka1029

Answer (score 1):

Well, a String containing `something\?` in Java looks like:

```
String query = "a b c id\\? e f name\\? empid\\? i value\\? j";
```

You want to replace any string ending with `\?` by a single character `?`. In Regex, you need to escape additionally both `\` and `?` with another slash (in Java two slashes) since they both have a special meaning, therefore matching `c\?` ends up in Java Regex as `c\\\\\\?` where first 4 slashes match literally in Regex using Java a `\` character and the last two ones together `\\?` matches literally a `?` character.

Considering the input above, your code would rather look like this:

```
query = query
        .replaceAll("id\\\\\\?", "?")
        .replaceAll("name\\\\\\?", "?")
        .replaceAll("empid\\\\\\?", "?")
        .replaceAll("value\\\\\\?", "?");

// a b c ? e f ? emp? i ? j
```

Note, the order is important since the `id\?` gets replaced by `?` even in the suffix of `empid\?` which is not what you want, because with the first replacement you end up with `emp` only. So this looks more correct to me:

```
query = query
        .replaceAll("empid\\\\\\?", "?")
        .replaceAll("id\\\\\\?", "?")
        .replaceAll("name\\\\\\?", "?")
        .replaceAll("value\\\\\\?", "?");

// a b c ? e f ? ? i ? j
```

You might want to change to `[a-z]+` (small latin letters from `a` to `z`) to match all the range of possible words:

```
query = query.replaceAll("\\w+\\\\\\?", "?");

// a b c ? e f ? ? i ? j
```

If the number of words to be matched is limited, you might want to separate them using `|` if there are not too many of them:

```
query = query
        .replaceAll("(id|name|empid|value)\\\\\\?", "?");

// a b c ? e f ? ? i ? j
```

... or  use the `Set` and `String#join(delimeter, iterable)` to build the Regex first, which is useful in larger number of words to be matched:

```
Set<String> set = Set.of("id", "name", "empid", "value");

query = query
        .replaceAll(String.format("(%s)\\\\\\?", String.join("|", set)), "?");

// a b c ? e f ? ? i ? j
```